# Cancel a suggested edit

Tags: feature-request, edits, review, suggested-edits, cancel

It happened many times that while I was submitting an edit to a question, someone else edited the same question (to improve code formatting, to correct a typo in the title, etc.) and got his edit approved. So, my edit became irrelevant and useless.

In this case, I think it could be useful to be able to cancel my own edits while it's still pending review.